# Diagram for SDLC Straitegy

Tags: asp.net, diagram, sdlc

Hi i am making asp.net website
and i am following SDLC Straitegy
so which diagrams are required to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what diagrams you need!

Diagrams should not be drawn for thr sake of drawing a diagram. It should add value to your development process.

Having said that, You might want to make a Class diagram and a Sequence Diagram for starters. Drawing the overall system architecture wont hurt either.

Comment: @Midhat, Thank you for feedback but i want the list of diagram to be useful in SDLC Straitegy

Comment: Like I said. It depends on teh SDLC process. For OO development like asp.net, UML is typically used. You can find a list of UML diagrams at http://vinci.org/uml/diags.html

Comment: and http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/umlDiagrams.htm

Comment: and http://atlas.kennesaw.edu/~dbraun/csis4650/A&D/UML_tutorial/diagrams.htm